# Move Table from One Database to another

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlcipher-android

I have two databases one is SQLite `db_1` and the other SQLCipher `db_2`. I want to move a table from `db_1` to `db_2`.

Since I am using [SQLCipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher) in one of the databases, I can't `ATTACH` the databases and copy Table and its contents from one to the other.

Is it possible with either database queries or Android Code or both to somehow move the table to `db_2` and then delete Table in `db_1` in `onUpgrade()`.

**Note :**

When trying to `ATTACH` the database I got the following error

```
Failure 26 (file is encrypted or is not a database) on 0xab61cb98 when executing 'ATTACH DATABASE '/data/data/com.example/databases/DATABASE.db' AS DB;'
```

Comment: Why can't you use ATTACH? Doesn't SQLCipher add the KEY option?

Comment: @CL. Because `db_1` and `db_2` are two different types of databases. I assumed attempting to attach a non-encrypted database in an encrypted one or vice versa should not be possible. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know; I've never used SQLCipher. But why didn't you try?

Comment: @CL. simply seemed illogical, I will however try and let you know.

Comment: @CL. Just tried `ATTACH`, didn't work. Got the error added in question.

Comment: I asked for ATTACH with KEY.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134483/discussion-between-abbas-and-cl).

Comment: @CL. Tried ATTACH with Key, got essentially the same error `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26)`.